# Recovering red box for hyperlink

Tags: hyperref

Somehow I managed to accidentally remove the red boxes surrounding hyperlink. All I am doing is `\usepackage{hyperref}`. How do I recover the boxes?

I realize this is a bit of an ironic question considering everyone hates the red boxes, but I need it in this particular instance.

A minimum working example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}


  \hypersetup{pdftitle={main.pdf},
        colorlinks=false,
        linkbordercolor=red,
        urlbordercolor=red,
        bookmarksnumbered=true
    }

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents



 \section{test}

 \section{test2}

This is testing hyperref


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What other packages are you using that might have caused this? What `\documentclass`? Do you have a `\hypersetup` anywhere?

Comment: @Werner article class, and no, I deleted the hypersetup hoping it would fix it

Comment: So then it must be some package that you've loaded. What packages do you load in addition to [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)?

Comment: A lot, but the only ones for formatting are hyperref and fancy

Comment: @Werner I posted a minimum working example. I get black hyperlinks

Comment: @Werner it appears Steve Jobs has been messing with me. See answer below

Comment: Note that `hyperref` should almost always be the last package you load unless you know you're dealing with an exception (e.g. `cleveref` must come afterwards).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this as follows --

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\hypersetup{pdftitle={main.pdf},
    colorlinks=false,
    linkbordercolor=red
}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents



    \section{test}

    \section{test2}

    This is testing hyperref


\end{document}
```

Here is the result -

[image]

That's what you wanted. Right ? If the problem persist, try some other viewer, **I could not see the red boxes in mac default viewer ("preview"). Adobe reader worked for me.** Honestly, I don't know why I can't see them in preview.

For further options -- see [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks)

Comment: This is just making the font red for some odd reason...

Comment: Not working either

Comment: ok, post a MWE, I and/or others can look into the problem.

Comment: I posted a MWE :)

Comment: see the answer now, I have edited it.

Comment: Hah! How strange! I can't see it in preview or the PDF-renderer for TexShop, but it works in Adobe! Thanks so much

Comment: I have initiated a question around this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37971932/mac-preview-vs-adobe-acrobat-reader-dc

Comment: Perhaps it is best to ask it on super user for apple enthusiasts? http://superuser.com/

Comment: `hyperref` should be loaded last with only very few exceptions (e.g. `cleveref` is the best known).